# How to link to a git commit from a different Github repo from an issue description

Tags: git, github

I created an issue on a Github repo like so:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I put in 2 different git commit hashes, one became a hotlink the other didn't, and I strongly presume it's simply because one is in this repo the other is in a different repo in our org.

Here is the raw text:

```
replicate error with:
* API - checkout master - 72b3071229fe65eb5b10e17e9422206fcf4fd83e
* web - checkout dev - cf1763873c46234673fd5ff78b9f52e8b7bde19a
```

is there a way to hyperlink to the commit from a different repo in our org?

Comment: Can't you create a link manually while editing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use syntax `User@SHA` or `Username/Repository@SHA`.

See https://help.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/autolinked-references-and-urls#commit-shas